# django how to make address model unique - based on house and postcode/zipcode

Tags: python, django, django-models

How would I setup a model in Django so that it creates unique entries based on a house (name/number) and a postcode/zipcode?

eg I currently have the address model in django as:

```
class Address(models.Model): 
    building = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    sub_building = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and am trying to access an existing model (or create a new one) with:

```
address, created = Address.objects.get_or_create(postcode=postcode, building=building)
```

which is later updated with the full address data:

```
Address.objects.filter(pk=address.pk).update(**defaults)
```

However this currently keeps on creating new entries for the same address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add a unique constraint for a pair building, postcode.
In django it can be achieved via unique_together https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ("building", "postcode")
```

Then what you really need is not a get_or_create but update_or_create method.

```
address, created = Address.objects.update_or_create(
    postcode=postcode, building=building, defaults=defaults)
```

Comment: Thanks, does the unique_together make a primary key? How would I access it?